# How do you change the difficulty in Bayonetta 2?

Tags: bayonetta-2

I just started Bayonetta 2, and I picked the "medium" difficulty (2nd climax). After finishing the prologue, this seems like it still might be a little bit too rough for me. Can I change the difficulty down to 1st climax without restarting the whole game?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the difficulty in the Chapter Select screen.  When you select a Chapter, there's a "Menu" option on the right, in that menu there's a "Change Difficulty" option.
If you're in the middle of a chapter and it's too hard, you can return to the Chapter Select screen through the menu(+), but you'll lose your progress.

The game records your rank per chapter, so I believe you'll be able to progress through chapters no matter what difficulty you pick.